# Pass informations from Angular to fmt JSTL tag

Tags: angularjs, angular, jstl

Is there a way to pass informations from Angular to a fmt JSTL tag ? 
and do something like that :

```
<fmt:message key="{{myInformation}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's impossible, because JSTL tags are executed in server side, and javascript in the client side.